# Elixir/Phoenix query incl quantity

Tags: psql, phoenix-framework, elixir

I have following tables in my db:

```
schema "foods" do
field :name, :string
has_many :order_items, MyApp.OrderItem
end

schema "order_items" do
field :quantity, :integer, default: 1
field :price, :integer
belongs_to :food, MyApp.Food
```

Order items keeps the food_id, as well as quantity. Now I'm trying to create a query that will show how much each food item has been ordered. This is what i have so far:

```
fooditems = Repo.all(from p in OrderItem, join: f in Food, on: p.food_id == f.id,
                     group_by: f.name, select: {f.name, count(p.id)}, order_by: count(p.id))
```

Basically, I have two questions: 1) How can I make quantity field(from order item table) be also included in the query count? For example, if in order item the quantity is 2, the count() will only count is as only 1, so how can I make the count() to count not only by id, but also include the quantity(from order item table, quantity field)?

Additionally, I'm not sure how to call the query from the html. I've tried

```
            <%= for item <- @fooditems do %>
                <tr>
                <td><%= item.name %></td>
                </tr>
            <% end %>
```

But it returns argument error, so I believe, I'm just calling it the wrong way with item.name. Generally, I want to have a table that will list food names, and the respective quantity (from order_item table, incl quantity field).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're doing a group_by on the Food's `name`, I'm guessing you want the sum of quantity. Here's how I would do it:

```
Repo.all(from p in OrderItem,
           join: f in Food,
           on: p.food_id == f.id,
           group_by: f.name,
           select: %{name: f.name, count: count(p.id), quantity: sum(p.quantity)},
           order_by: count(p.id))
```

This generates the following query:

> SELECT f1."name", count (o0."id"), sum (o0."quantity") FROM "order_items" AS o0 INNER JOIN "foods" AS f1 ON o0."food_id" = f1."id" GROUP BY f1."name" ORDER BY count (o0."id")

For the second part, `Repo.all` returns a list of whatever you have in the `select` part of your query, which in your case was a tuple, and not a map, but you tried to access it like a Map.

For your original query, this will work:

```
<%= for {food_name, count} <- @fooditems do %>
```

For the query I wrote above, which returns a Map, you can access the fields easily:

```
<%= for item <- @fooditems do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.name %></td>
    <td><%= item.count %></td>
    <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you Dogbert! So, I should have just used the sum() for calculating the quantity, instead of count. As for the tuples, I see what i made wrong,  I will follow your suggestion and use map instead!

Comment: Yes, `count` would return the number of orders while `sum(quantity)` will add up all quantities of those orders.